# dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder = false not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods, code-cleanup

I use the latest VS 2022 (17.2.6)

I activated all code cleanup fixers

My .editorconfig contains

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder = false
```

My extension's class should be

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection Add(this IServiceCollection services, ...)
  {
    ...
```

but when I clean up, the cleanup provide the following code :

```
namespace Product.Folder;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection Add(this IServiceCollection services, ...)
  {
    ...
```

The only way is to deactivate the fixer named "Apply namespace matches folder preferences" in VS options, but I want to deactivate this rule only in some folders.
Did I forget something?